# Como insertar el id que se genero de una tabla en otra en PHP Y MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Hola comunidad hoy tengo un pequeño problema que he intentado resolver pero no más no llego al punto, lei que se esto no tiene nada que ver con la base de datos si no con la programación que tengo en php y bueno, tengo algunas tablas relacionas ejemplo:

dficha->
idficha,idlibro,idcarrera

mlibro->
idlibro,campo1,campo2

ccarrera->
idcarrera,campo1,campo2

La tabla general es dficha donde se almacenan los id de las otras dos tablas, bueno y detallando mas a fondo yo tengo un formulario en php donde tengo los campos del libro y de la carrera, en este caso lleno los campos correspondientes y el campo de carrera tengo los valores predeterminados 
ejemplo de carrera: administracion,ingenieria

hasta ahí tengo todo bien, envio mi formulario y se llenan las tablas, pero aquí viene el problema que el id de la tabla **mlibro** obvio es autoincremental, pero el idlibro de la tabla **dficha** no lo es! y lo que quiero es mandar el id que se genero al ingresar en este caso, un registro nuevo dentro de la tabla **mlibro**  que puedo hacer para mandar ese id que se generó a la tabla **dficha** por su ayuda Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira es fácil obtener el id de lo que acabas de insertar te dejo la página de la documentación de php y el código de ejemplo, en la parte de `$mysqli->insert_id` con esto optienes el id autoincremental, después solo sería cuestión de hacer otro insert en tu otra tabla **difcha**.

[Esto es lo que pone en la documentación de PHP para `insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php):

> La función `mysqli_insert_id()` devuelve el ID generado por una
>   consulta en una tabla con una columna que tenga el atributo
>   AUTO_INCREMENT. Si la última consulta no fue una sentencia INSERT o
>   UPDATE o si la tabla modificada no tiene una columna con el atributo
>   AUTO_INCREMENT, está función devolverá cero.

Como no has compartido ningún código en tu pregunta, te voy a poner el ejemplo que viene directamente en la documentación de PHP enlazada arriba. En ese ejemplo se crea una tabla temporal que se utiliza para realizar una inserción, leer el último ID insertado, y luego borra la tabla temporal. **En tu código seguramente no necesites crear/borrar una tabla temporal** y bastará con que hagas `$mysqli->insert_id` o `mysqli_insert_id()` (dependiendo de si usas el método orientado a objetos o el procedimental) después del INSERT.

> **Ejemplo #1 Ejemplo de $mysqli->insert_id**
>
> Estilo orientado a objetos
>
> ```
> <?php
> $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "mi_usuario", "mi_password", "world");
>
> /* check connection */
> if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
>     printf("Error de conexión: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
>     exit();
> }
>
> $mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");
>
> $query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
> $mysqli->query($query);
>
> printf ("Nuevo registro con el id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
>
> /* drop table */
> $mysqli->query("DROP TABLE myCity");
>
> /* close connection */
> $mysqli->close();
> ?>
> ```

Comment: **¡Peligro!** Este código BORRARÁ TU TABLA: `$mysqli->query("DROP TABLE myCity");` -1

Comment: @A.Cedano Este código no es malicioso, es una copia literal del [ejemplo que viene en la documentación oficial de PHP enlazada en la propia respuesta](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: De hecho @A.Cedano tambien tiene `$mysqli->query("CREATE TABLE myCity LIKE City");`, para crear la tabla ya de ultimo la borra solo es un ejemplo.

Comment: Cualquier persona desprevenida podría tomar el ejemplo tal cual, ejecutarlo sobre una tabla en producción y terminaría borrando dicha tabla. Aunque esté así en el Manual de PHP no veo el sentido de la sentencia `DROP TABLE` ¿Tú le ves algún sentido o utilidad para resolver el problema ?

Comment: El código crea la tabla y luego la borra, teniendo sentido en ese caso. ¿Podría ser un ejemplo más básico sin el drop? Sí, sin duda. Pero eso no lo hace malicioso. Y pensar que el código del sitio oficial de PHP es malicioso (y votar negativo a una respuesta que cita textualmente la documentación oficial por ello) es ridículo.

Comment: Si toma el **"Ejemplo"** tal cual como dices, imagínate cuantos ejemplos de la documentación oficial están perjudicando a tantos que apenas inician y quieren aprender, como te dice el amigo **Alvaro Montoro** es totalmente ridículo que alguien vote en negativo mi respuesta, me gustaría que te retractes de tu voto negativo @A.Cedano Cedano. ya que en este caso me perjudicas.

Comment: Si se leen mis comentarios, no he usado en ningún momento el término _malicioso_. Como ya dije, si un usuario inexperto copia el ejemplo tal cual, incluyendo el `DROP...` podría estar borrando una tabla con datos, en producción, de ahí mi advertencia sobre el **peligro** de este código. Además, el OP pregunta: _Como **insertar** el id que se generó de una tabla en otra en PHP Y MYSQL?_ Entonces el `DROP` en este caso sólo aporta valor negativo a la respuesta. Si lo eliminas, retiraré el -1. Pero si sigues manteniendo algo no sólo inútil (en este caso), sino además **peligroso** seguirá el -1.

Comment: @A.Cedano Es cierto que yo fui el que utilizó el término malicioso, porque no hay manera de considerar el código de arriba como peligroso, y el único motivo para votar negativo a la respuesta es considerar que es peligroso (que no lo es) y que la persona que responde lo hace de manera maliciosa. ¿Por qué el código de arriba no es peligroso? Porque  crea una tabla temporal, se inserta y se borra. Si un usuario inexperto copiara el código de arriba y lo pusiera en su código NO se borrarían sus tablas, el usuario estaría creando (innecesariamente) tablas temporales que serían borradas al final.

Comment: @A.Cedano Actualicé la respuesta para puntualizar eso, pero creo que estás siendo increíblemente estricto con tu votación. **OP no provee ningún código** para su problema y por eso Maghdiel (o cualquier otro usuario) se ve obligado a usar un código "no relacionado" para su respuesta... y puestos a usar cualquier código, **¿qué mejor código de ejemplo que el de la propia documentación oficial?**

Comment: Lo que suele hacer un usuario principiante es copiar el código y **cambiar los nombres de tablas / columnas** por los suyos propios. Creo que en poquísimos casos un usuario creará una tabla de prueba. A lo sumo insertará valores de prueba en su tabla. Aunque se ha editado la respuesta **el DROP** sigue ahí , como si el OP estuviese preguntando sobre cómo borrar una tabla. Sigo sin entender por qué insisten en dejar un DROP TABLE en esta respuesta, **cuando no aporta absolutamente nada a la solución del problema**.

Comment: Por cierto @AlvaroMontoro si votas positivo la respuesta aparecería con 0, no con -1 y Maghdiel se beneficiaría , por el momento de 8 puntos, de 10 cuando se elimine el DROP y si la respuesta resuelve el problema del OP tendrá mi upvote. Mi única intención es que se mejore la respuesta eliminando código más peligroso que útil.

Comment: @A.Cedano +1/-2 (Por eso está en -1). Le di un positivo porque **la respuesta es correcta y está citando textualmente el ejemplo de una fuente oficial**. Si crees que el ejemplo es peligroso, edítalo como ya hice yo y ponlo como tú consideres que es correcto... Es lo bueno de esta comunidad, todo el mundo puede colaborar en las respuestas para mejorarlas si hace falta.